# String formatting in C++ - optional values by namend

Tags: c++, string-formatting

I'm trying to write a tool that includes a string format in a config file, and the program will actually turn that into a string with the right values.

The order of the items in the format string is arbitrary, as is whether values are used at all.

In Python, I know that I'd be able to use something like:

```
values = { 'A': "foo", 'B': "bar", 'C': 4, 'D': 120 }
resultFormat = "{A}_{B}__{C:02d}"
result = resultFormat.format( **values )
```

However, the string formatting equivalents that I've found in C++ so far have required the values to be passed in by order, rather than by name. `boost::format` is the main one that I've been looking at so far, but that needs values to be passed in order.

The other option that I've gone with for the moment is using `boost::algorithm::replace_all`, but that doesn't allow for any kind of formatting (`{C:02d}` style).

Is there a good solution for this kind of thing in C++?

Thanks

Comment: If you're open to considering third party libraries, I think that [`fmt`](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt#examples) is great. It allows you to perform string formatting similar to the syntax of Python that you're describing.

Comment: boost::format does support reordering (using %#% to select)
`cout << format("%1% %2% %3% %2% %1% \n") % "11" % "22" % "333"; // 'simple' style`.  See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/format/doc/format.html#printf_directives for positional details

Comment: Thanks both. Those look interesting, but what I want to be able to do is reference them by name. So a user would, on the command-line, or in a config file, specify something like "%project%/%date%/%name%_v%version:03d%". I'd prefer to do this than have to explain to users which number refers to which item.